# Reducing GWT custom widget verbosity

Tags: gwt

My current process for custom widgets is the following:

1. Create my widget class - extending Composite;
2. Create a listener interface for this widget;
3. Create a listener collection interface - private inner class to the widget;
4. Create add/removeListener methods on the widget;
5. Inside the widget, fire the events on the listeners.

My listeners fire fine-grained events, such as `onEntityDisplayRequested(Entity entity)`, so I can't use the stock listeners.

While this achieves low coupling for the widget and allows for re-use, it's quite verbose. Is there a better way of handling design of custom widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a separate listener interface for every new widget.  E.g. [ClickListener](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ClickListener.html) is used by a variety of different widget classes.  Obviously, some custom widgets will require a new listener type, but that shouldn't be automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using these listeners to fire custom events, e.g. onEntityDisplayRequested(Entity e) , so I can't use the stock listeners.

Comment: Best - and only - answer so far. Winner!

Answer (score 2):

I think Java faced the same issue some time ago, and a solution was to have the PropertyChange events. They come with
- the PropertyEvent, that contains the source, the property name and the old+new values
- a PropertyChangeListener
- a PropertyChangeSupport, to which you can delegate the event firing, as well as the registering and unregistering the listeners.

You loose a bit of specificity (event are matched by their name as a string), but you can still fire fine-grained events and have some external class support.

I have not used this extensively in GWT, so I can't comment on efficiency aspects.